# What is the difference between と, たら and 時【とき】?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, time

First, I came across this sentence using と in a way I've never encountered before.

> ピノキオはうそを吐くと、鼻が長くなります。

My translation: When/As Pinocchio tells lies his nose becomes longer.

After a little research and based on the context of the sentence I figured this use of と must mean 'when' or 'as' as opposed to the 'and' meaning but then I started wondering what the difference is between this 'when' and the 時【とき】 'when' and the たら 'when' in terms of usage.

Comment: Do you focus on “one-time when” e.g. 戸を開けて見ると誰もいない or “recurring when” as in “春になると花が咲く”. I think they will make great difference. (All とき, と, たら, ば have these two usages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could all be translated to 'when' in English but:

AとB in this case indicates that A first happens, then immediately after B happens. This is the case in your example!

たら can have more uncertainty in it, i.e. it can be used to express sentences where you'd use 'if' in English.

I think of とき as 'the time when' or 'everytime when'.

Just offering my two cents here. I am still learning too!:)
I'm not good enough to provide the lengthy grammatical replies you usually get on this site, so sorry if it's a bit short. 
Anyway, at this level I find shorter answers more helpful. Hope you agree:)

Comment: You use と when B always happens when A happens (as in a rule). I think that's why it was used here: Pinocchio's nose grows every time he tells a lie.

Comment: Good answer, but the last paragraph is both irrelevant to the topic of the question, and not appropriate for this site. If you want to build a consensus on what length answers should be on the site, take it up on [JLU Meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/). It's also a little disrespectful... the people who write long answers are trying to be helpful by being complete, and even if it's not for you, some people appreciate that effort.

Comment: I don't think the intent of that comment was to speak down on the concept of long answers. I agree that short and simple answers are probably more helpful to people at lower levels of learning even if they gloss over some finer details.

Comment: That was definitely not the intention of my last paragraph:) edited now!

Answer (score 3):

#### Causality

In broad terms, I've noticed three kinds of constructions that loosely correlate to "if / then".  The main differences between these appear to be differences in emphasis and causal relationship.

- 行くと XX
  Tells us *whenever* someone goes, XX happens.  XX is an inevitable consequence of the verb.
- 行けば XX
  Tells us that *only if* someone goes, XX happens.  The verb is a precondition of XX.
- 行ったら XX
  Seems to be the most neutral.  If [verb], then XX; or possibly, after [verb], then XX.  This is less causally strict, and seems a bit more casual in that respect: "if you happen to go, or on the off chance that you go, then XX".

#### Timing

Various constructions are used to describe the order of events.  Among these,

- 行くと XX
  This still has strong causal overtones, so this is probably best glossed as "whenever [verb], XX".
- 行ったら
- 行ってから
  These two are often regarded as synonymous when describing the order of events.  One teacher of mine even suggested that -たら was a contraction of -てから, though it bears noting that Shogakukan, Daijirin, and others state that the -たら ending is the potential form of past auxiliary た, itself a contraction of たる, a contraction of て + ある.
  The basic sense is "[verb] happens, and then ..."
- 行くとき
  Literally, "the time when [subject] goes".  This more specifically refers to the point in time when the [verb] happens.