# Usage of 「と」in a sentence from Harry Potter

Tags: grammar, nuances, conditionals

In the following sentence

> ダーズリー一家【いっか】が目【め】を覚【さ】ます**と**、外【そと】はどんよりとした灰色【はいいろ】の空【そら】だった。

「と」is used in a place where I'd rather use 「とき」 or 「たら」.
I know that 「と」is used for inevitable conditions like facts of nature but it doesn't fit that sentence.

1. Does particle 「と」has another meaning similar to 「とき」in the context of the above sentence? 
   If so, is there a difference between the two?
2. Similarly「と」and 「たら」(I think the difference here would be 「と」being more formal than 「たら」).

Comment: Please see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc ...

Comment: It might also help to see how you believe the sentence should be translated (because on my reading と makes perfect sense here where as たら does not).

Comment: You can also refer to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33481/use-of-%E3%81%A8-in-these-two-sentences-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BC%E3%82%8B-or-%E3%81%82%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24523/using-%E3%81%A8-to-link-clauses-instead-of-%E3%81%A6), and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-and-%E6%99%82-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D).

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32435/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very subtle.「とき」puts more emphasis on time so usually reserved for more memorable occasions which often happened further back in time--like "the time when Sarah turned 30" would be a time to bust out「とき」.

- 「と」= "When the Dursleys woke up, the sky was..."
- 「とき」= "That time when
  the Dursleys woke up, the sky was..."

Cheers!